# How to get the exact actual parents width or height with an absolute positioning for childs?

Tags: position, height, width, absolute

Am creating elements and there childs dynamically, with different absolute positions, the childs have a left, top, width and height properties, the problem is whatever I tried, the parents width and height is always 0. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Crazyosachou/BU6Sh/).

```
var my_parent = document.getElementById('my_obj');

var chld1 = document.createElement('div');

my_parent.appendChild(chld1);

$(chld1).css({
    position:'absolute',
    left:10, 
    top:50,
    width:60,
    height:20,
    background:'pink'
});

alert($(my_parent).width());
```

Is there a simple way to get the width & height of the parent? (javascript & jQuery since evrything is happening dynamically)

Or I have to create a function that goes over all the childs & childs of childs, check the minimum left, top, then included the width & height of childs... that might take me days? or there's magical JavaScript or jQuery plugin that gives you that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your child' absolute position. whenever child uses absolute position, it will not fill the parent. So either don't use absolute positioning or either give the parents a fixed width

Comment: The problem with the child is already presented , and the issue indeed is that case, so this answer is not helping at all , but thx anyway.